# Open Xiomi native browser in android?

Tags: java, android

How to open the xiomi (Mi Note 4 browser) native browser programatically in android. I am able to open chrome browser. here i code for chrome

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                    "android.intent.action.VIEW");
browserIntent
                    .addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
browserIntent
                    .addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
browserIntent.putExtra("create_new_tab", false);

browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
// browserIntent.setType("text/html");
browserIntent.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.sbrowser",
                            "com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.SBrowserMainActivity");

browserIntent.putExtra(
                    "com.android.browser.application_id",
                    "com.sec.android.app.sbrowser");

// browserIntent.setFlags(32768);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: It's because you've set Chrome as your default browser.

Comment: Do you have to be specific with the browser? It might not work on other devices. Also, good job with the edit. ;)

Comment: i mean i have to open MI browser on button click , with help of this code i am ble to open sbrowser.

Comment: @Lance Toth yes it specific to browser, i have to open Mi native browser which avaialble in mi new device.

Comment: Do you know the package name of the native browser? I don't have it here. You can see the package name in the app detail screen in the system settings. If you have it, just remove the `setClassName` and provide the packagename with `setPackage` to your intent.

Comment: yes "com.android.browser" found ,  but not class name

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with adding `com.android.browser` as package and remove the class name method?

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
browserIntent.setPackage("com.android.browser");
startActivity(browserIntent);
```